# Why use Consul with Kubernetes, Docker, Mesos?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos, consul

Most container services have some sort of built in service discovery mechanism. So why is it that someone would still incorporate Consul into their setup? I know that Consul provides other benefits besides service discovery, such as K/V store, Consul templates, and service monitoring, however none of these seem like a big enough benefit.

Comment: This question seems very subjective and heavily dependent on your use cases.  Maybe K/V storage is not useful to use, but is useful to others?  One pattern one might use is having redundant copies of a service where only one instance should be active at any given time.  This can be done by having instances contend over a distributed lock in Consul.  Consul can couple discoverability of said service to the owner of the lock, guaranteeing all client requests go to the same single master (whichever instance holds the lock).

Comment: I understand that this question might be highly subjective, but that is what I am asking for. Personally I don't know much about containerization or much about these services, but it seems like adding Consul just complicates the picture. People might have specific reasons as to why they incorporated such a service and that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I won't answer on behalf of another site, I found a better answer at https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-use-Consul-or-other-Service-Discovery-tool-along-with-Kubernetes-that-has-this-functionality-built-it

Answer (score 1):

It's simple - it depends on your application. If it needs those features Consul have, and which other systems don't, then you can go for it.

Besides that, there are a lot of Hashicorp products tightly integrated with a Consul in part of HA. Vault, Nomad and Terraform. Consul can be used like a variant of ZooKeeper, but Raft based. We use it that way.

Another concern, maybe you would like to have another layer of indirection in your system. Consul cluster can stand for verifying connectivity between various remote parts and etc.

So, it's not about how big is the advantage, it's about your very specific requirements and limitations in your very own moment.